# how can I start a MVC server from a folder in my local system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my local system I have published an Asp.net core Web app. How can i start a server from that folder which will listen to user request. I have tried Httplistener and Weblistener . But routing is not working in both case.

My http.sys code :
`

```
var builder = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel()

        .UseStartup<Startup>()

        .UseHttpSys(options =>
        {
            // The following options are set to default values.
            options.Authentication.Schemes = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.AuthenticationSchemes.None;
            options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
            options.MaxConnections = null;

            options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:9000");
        }).UseContentRoot(@"path to my publish folder")

        .Build();

            builder.Run();`
```

I am trying with http.sys . In this case I am able to start the server but routing is not working .

Comment: Please show us enough of your code that we can see what you've done so far.

Comment: Hi Every one. I was able to do this by implementing a custom MVC server using IServer . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows, you can use Internet Information Server (IIS) to host an ASP.Net MVC application.
Please see link below for further information: 
https://levelnis.co.uk/blog/configure-mvc-website-in-iis

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I am looking for a way to start a server on a folder . something similar to Http listener.(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx)